# How do I delete all rows that don't meet a criteria, especially when names are used in multiple rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have athletic letter winners in my school (Name01 - Name07).  Athletes get a chenille letter when they get their very first varsity letter. I need to know who won their first letter this year and if they won more than one this year, keep only the earliest one (fall sports have a prefix 1, winter 2, spring 3).  I want to delete all rows for an individual if they:

1. Won a letter only in previous years (they have a blank entry for this year).  There are more columns for those previous years in the full sheet.
2. Won letters this year, but they weren't their first one (they have a 2+ next to their name)

On my sheet, it should delete all rows except for Rows 8 and 10.  Name04 got their first letter in 2Boys Ice Hockey (winter) and Name05 got their first letter in 1Field Hockey (fall).

I generalized the sheet the best I could, getting rid of personal data. You can find it here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13uuMfxK22_fmjuWy8QykodoxV5RB_lAjEhyhUi6YQ-g/edit?usp=sharing

I'm hoping that a script that will do that for this sheet can be expanded on for the full spreadsheet.

I don't know where to start.  I have limited programming experience other than grabbing scripts others have written and tweaking them where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("name");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!r[0] && r[1]) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  AppsScript doesn't like the second = in row 5.  What does that accomplish?